# resultMap alway report "must match constructor, id, result, asssociation, collection, discriminator"

Tags: mybatis, mapper

My mybatis mapper file always report the following error message:

> The content of element type "resultMap" must match 
>    "(constructor?,id*,result*,association*,collection*,discriminator?)".

and here is my resultMap config:

```xml
<resultMap type="com.sp.sysmanage.domain.UserInfoDO" id="user">
    <result column="USER_ID" property="userID"/>  
    <result column="USER_USERNAME" property="userName"/>
    <result column="USER_PASSWORD" property="password"/>
    <result column="USER_FIRST_LOGIN" property="firstLogin"/>
    <result column="USER_LAST_LOGIN_DATE" property="lastLoginDate"/>
    <reulst column="USER_STATUS" property="status"/>
</resultMap>
```

Anyone can help to see what detailed error in my resultMap config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo: `<reulst>` at the end, it should be `<result>`

Comment: in my case, that was a comment that was not compatible with XML (`//` instead of `<!- ->`)

Answer (score 4):

As the error is saying:

> The content of element type "resultMap" must match
> "(constructor?,id*,result*,association*,collection*,discriminator?)"

the order is important:

first `constructor`

then `<id>`

then `<result>`

then `<association>`

then `<collection>`

then `discriminator`